# SQL: copy hierarchy from source to target which has identity columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID  TXT  PID
12  A    13
13  B    15
15  C    Null
```

Need to write an srpoc which will insert this source data to a target table which has identity columns in it

```
ID   TXT  PID
1    A    2
2    B    3
3    C    Null
```

In the target table the ID is identity column and PID is foreign key of ID column.

Below is what I tried with taking tmp tables. But I getting this result instead of actual one. Please help me.

```
ID  TXT  PID
1    A    1
2    B    2
3    C    Null


drop table #tmp

Create table #tmp
(
id int identity (1,1) constraint pk_tab Primary key,
Txt varchar(10),
ParentId int NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_Categories_ParentId
        FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES #tmp
)

insert into #tmp(Txt)
Select Source.s from 
(Select f.ID,f.T as s,g.T as p from
(select 12 as ID, 'A' as T, 13 as PID
union all
Select 13,'B',15
union all
select 15,'C',null
) f
left join 
(select 12 as ID, 'A' as T, 13 as PID
union all
Select 13,'B',15
union all
select 15,'C',null
)g
on f.ID = g.PID
) Source

Select * from #tmp

update #tmp 
SET
    #tmp.ParentId = #tmp.ID
FROM
    #tmp
INNER JOIN
    (Select f.ID,f.T as s,g.T as p from
(select 12 as ID, 'A' as T, 13 as PID
union all
Select 13,'B',15
union all
select 15,'C',null
) f
left join 
(select 12 as ID, 'A' as T, 13 as PID
union all
Select 13,'B',15
union all
select 15,'C',null
)g
on f.ID = g.PID
) Source
ON
    #tmp.Txt = Source.p

Select * from #tmp
```

Comment: This is much easier to do if you create a new column in the target table with "OriginalID".  Then the copy just involves an insert and an update with join.

Comment: can you give me exact SQL for that?

Comment: Also I m not allowed to add any columns in the #tmp target table

Comment: not allowed?  by who?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how the extra column is not allowed.  Unless this is a homework assignment / job interview / puzzle you can simply change the code like this:

```
Create table #tmp
(
id int identity (1,1) constraint pk_tab Primary key,
Txt varchar(10),
ParentId int NULL,
OriginalId int NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_Categories_ParentId
        FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES #tmp
)
```

Comment: the temp table is actually a table in my DB, for sample sake i put the temp table here in the blog,. so therei no option for me to change th schema

Comment: @user3787610 - there is no way to do this without a temporary table... that I know of.  You need to be able to save the original IDs and their association to the new IDs.